# How to add custom command on new version of "To Do" from outlook using Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-web-addins

How to add custom button on new version of "To Do" on outlook using Visual Studio?

[image]

What I am trying to do is add a button into the "to do" section, I have seen articles on adding things into the mail section, but haven't found anything for the to do section.